# Angular2 material dialog box is getting close while click on the browser backbutton, Can we avoid this?

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

Angular2 material dialog box is getting close while click on the browser back button, Can we avoid this?

Comment: sorry but, do you want to avoid the browser navigation while dialog is open?

Comment: But I want to handle some functionality with browser back button inside popup, I have a stepper inside popup, I want to navigate that stepper with browser buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onpopstate = function(event) {

  // "event" object seems to contain value only when the back button is clicked
  // and if the pop state event fires due to clicks on a button
  // or a link it comes up as "undefined" 

  if(event){
    // Code to handle back button or prevent from navigation
  }
  else{
    // Continue user action through link or button
  }
}
```

this is the javascript handler for buttons, that as i wrote above returns undefined when is clicked another navigation button.
You could implement some conditional functionality inside dialog handler.

Hope this help

Comment: Please consider adding a link to the `onpopstate` event.